# Firebase - Ocorreu um erro desconhecido ao criar o projeto. Tente novamente

Tags: firebase, google

Tentei criar um projeto no Firebase e não consigo, já tentei de várias formas diferentes (mudando nome do projeto, mudando o país, tentando com outra conta do Google... etc..) e mesmo assim aparece a mensagem conforme imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não existem detalhes sobre o erro, não sei qual o motivo, tenho apenas 2 projetos na minha conta do Google, sei que existe um limite da conta free do Firebase, mas com certeza são mais do que 3 (dois que tenho atualmente e mais esse novo que tento criar). Alguém teria mais alguma informação para tentar ajudar?

Comment: Sugiro que você contacte alguém da equipa de suporte do Firebase. Veja como fazer isso [aqui](http://firebase.google.com/support/)

Comment: me parece que alguns dos serviços do google estava com algum tipo de problema, agora normalizou, mas eu iria entrar em contato com o suporte do Firebase mesmo, caso o serviço não tivesse normalizado. Obrigado.

Comment: Certo. Encontrei [log](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/18013) aqui que menciona o problema que você falou. Sempre que tiver um problema, verifique em https://status.firebase.google.com

Comment: Blz Rosário, obrigado.

Answer (score -3):

Isso também aconteceu comigo.
Mas foi porque eu estava usando uma extensão no Chrome que alterava meu CORS, e estava interferindo na criação do banco de dados.
Abra seu navegador em modo anônimo, ou se tiver algum plugin como mencionei, desinsta-le.